# New line without carriage return in assembly language

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, dosbox

I am doing a program on dosbox assembly where i print 0 to 9 diagonally. Here is my current code

```
code segment
assume cs:code, ds:code
org 100h

start:
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 30h
mov ch, 30h
int 21h

again:
inc dl  ;output next number
mov bl, dl
mov dl, 0ah ;new line
int 21h
mov dl, 20h ;space
int 21h
mov dl, bl
int 21h

inc ch  ;increment counter
cmp ch, 39h ;if counter is at 9 end program
je terminate    
loop again


terminate:
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

The problem is when i add a new line, the cursor goes back to the beginning of the next line, so printing diagonally is impossible. Is there a way that I can print a new line, but the cursor stays on the current position? I've read somewhere that 'Line Feed' can solve my problem, but it has been changed to 'New Line', where after adding a new line, the cursor automatically goes back to the starting position ala automatic 'Carriage Return'

---

EDIT: Thanks everyone for checking out this question. We aren't allowed to use those other functions aside from loop, jmp, and cmp. My friend figured out how to do it, but I still don't understand maybe 2/3 of their code, mainly on the again2 and jump loops. Code: https://pastebin.com/Vji29VL3.

Comment: You can of course print the correct amount of spaces, or set the cursor position directly.

Comment: You can obviously work around this by printing an increasing number of spaces on each line.  I'm not familiar with obsolete DOS / BIOS system calls, but I think at least some ways of outputting text do require CR / LF, and leaving out the CR would give you the behaviour you want.  There are many different groups of `int` functions besides the `int 21h` DOS system calls.  See http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm for the canonical list of 16-bit software-interrupt functions, and other links in the x86 tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: thanks for the links, will check it out! On the other hand, is it possible to use int 10h to set the cursor position after inserting a new line for the next input like the person above said?

Comment: the BIOS "set cursor position" will override it's current location, i.e. its independent on any amount of CR/LF outputted before it.

Comment: I think it should be noted that if you ran this under real DOS it would work. This is actually a deficiency in DOSBox's DOS emulation where line feed acts like a carriage return and line feed when using `int 21h`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print numbers diagonally in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394404/print-numbers-diagonally-in-assembly)

Comment: @Kirk I looked at your friends code and understand you don't get 2/3 of it. Today I wrote an all new solution to your previous question about the same thing. This time I tested it in DOSBox 0.74. Please take a look at it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394404/print-numbers-diagonally-in-assembly/47501673#47501673 and maybe let me know if this code you can understand?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to BIOS functions would be to write directly to video.

```
      mov     al, 30H
      mov     cx, B800H
      mov     es, cx
      xor     di, di               ; Change if you don't want to start at top/left.
      mov     cx, 161              ; STOSB has already incremented by one.

Loop:
      stosb
      add     di, cx
      inc     al
      cmp     al, 9
      jbe     Loop
```

Of course this makes a few assumption, particularly that you're writing to page 0 and attribute is set to something that will actually display. If you prefer you could also establish an attribute in AH, then use STOSW and only add 160 to DI each time.

Comment: To accomodate the space character that the OP is also outputting, your 161 (160) need to be 163 (162).

Comment: Not forgetting to mention that he might need `0xb000` if he happens to own a MDA ;-)